# iOS Directory Structure - What's Snapshots file?

Tags: ios, xcode, directory-structure

I was digging into the directory structure of iOS /Library/Caches/ folder and I found a file named "com.BlueChips.MyApp" and another file named "Snapshots" inside the above folder.

The name of my app's bundle is same as the first file I found - "com.BlueChips.MyApp".

I have been working on this app for a long time - over 6 months and I have no recollection of creating those files, especially "Snapshots" inside /Library/Caches/ folder. So I am wondering whether these are system generated files or were they actually somehow created by me?

I am curious about them because so that I can delete them before my app submission - don't want Apple to reject my app just because they found some stray files in my /Library/Cache folder when launching my app.

On XCode or Instruments, is it possible to get a list of all files that are already present or created when my app is launched?

Answer (score 3):

It is used for state maintainance. when you go to background mode app will be terminated in most of the cases. so when you switch between apps the animation ios gives uses this images, just to show the last state of application inorder to make it look good.

in some cases when your app crashes there'll be a screenshot also.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found out that the /Library/Caches/Snapshots folder keeps the snapshots of your apps. Especially when you switch between apps or you press home button and then launch back into your app, it tries to bring up a screenshot from this particular folder.